# Android: How to change the drawableLeft of a Button

Tags: android, button, drawable

If I initially set a bitmap to drawableLeft(in xml or by setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds in onStart, etc), then change(setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds again) to another bitmap or AnimationDrawable, causing a 'StackOverflowError'. I did not find any API to release the original drawLeft in google doc. Is there any solution for this?

```
public class TestLinearlayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button locationTitleButton = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        locationTitleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LocationTitleButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        locationTitleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               locationTitleButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.loading, 0, 0, 0);



            }
        });

    }
}
```

There is a default resourse in layout file for leftDrawable. After the above setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds in onClick, there is crash

```
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187): java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.util.LongSparseArray.get(LongSparseArray.java:87)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.util.LongSparseArray.get(LongSparseArray.java:79)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getCachedDrawable(Resources.java:1746)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1664)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
11-14 18:18:13.321: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2187):     at and
```

Comment: Wow SO will crash when you run your code...that's pretty funny.  Seriously can you post some code.

Comment: add code and crash stack

Comment: is it complete code for onClickListener?

Comment: Also post the layout.xml file, and also you've tried the obvious fixes...recompile project by cleaning it (using Eclipse).  Making sure the Resources are in the resource file.

Comment: Hmm ran the code fine button changed pictures and got no errors like yours.  Let me know all your parameters, SDK version, Eclipse version, Android (ADK) version, platform you are programming on.